# Qual é o nome português para goji berry?

Tags: significado

Alguns frutos tornaram-se mais conhecidos no Brasil nos últimos anos, muito em função de seus possíveis benefícios à saúde. Entre estes frutos, destaco o **blueberry**, o **cranberry** e o **goji berry**. Tenho bastante curiosidade para saber os nomes dessas frutas em português. Nos dois primeiros casos, encontrei os nomes. Blueberry é **mirtilo** e cranberry é **oxicoco**. No entanto, não encontrei o nome do goji berry. Seria simplesmente *goji*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conforme o dicionário da Porto Editora as traduções pt-PT são:

> [blueberry](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/blueberry)  - mirtilo
>
> [cranberry](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/cranberry)  - arando; mirtilo; uva-do-monte

Não encontrei tradução para *goji berry*, talvez por serem duas palavras distintas, mas consegui encontrar para *goji*:

> [goji](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/goji) - góji

No linguee, curiosamente, aparece sem acento:

> [goji berry](http://www.linguee.pt/ingles-portugues/traducao/goji+berries.html) - baga de goji

No exemplo da maior cadeia de supermercados do país também aparece sem acento:

[image]

No priberam está com acento também:

> **gó·ji** (inglês goji) substantivo masculino
>
> 1. [Botânica]  Designação vulgar comum a duas espécies de plantas do géneroLycium, da família das solanáceas, cultivadas pelas suas bagas
>    comestíveis.
> 2. [Botânica]  Baga que constitui o fruto dessas plantas.Ver imagem
>
> "góji", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
> 2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/g%C3%B3ji [consultado em
> 13-07-2016].

*Resumindo ao que me parece a tradução correta é **baga de góji** mas talvez alguns prefiram usar o nome "estrangeiro" do fruto (estrangeirismo).*

Answer (score 7):

Em Portugal, a *goji berry* chama-se «baga goji». *[Wolfberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goji)* é um nome alternativo em inglês.

O dicionário priberam indica a escrita alternativa «[góji](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/g%C3%B3ji)», mas uma pesquisa rápida indica 500 vezes mais usos de «[bagas goji](https://www.google.pt/webhp?#q=%22bagas+goji%22)» que de «[bagas góji](https://www.google.pt/webhp?#q=%22bagas+g%C3%B3ji%22)».

O Aulete [não](http://www.aulete.com.br/g%C3%B3ji) parece [reconhecer](http://www.aulete.com.br/goji) esta palavra.

---

Já agora, em Portugal o *cranberry* chama-se arando. O nome «oxicoco» não seria normalmente reconhecido em Portugal.
Alternativamente, pode ser conhecido por arando-vermelho ou mirtilo-vermelho.

Comment: Não queres indicar fontes nisto? O Priberam tem *góji*, com acento.

Comment: @Jacinto , a minha fonte foi vê-lo escrito. Como está na resposta do JorgeB.

Comment: @JorgeB. e ANeves, e como é que pronunciam? O meu instinto é pronunciar como se tivesse acento; sem acento pronuncia-se como *guji*, fica tónica a útlima sílaba.

Comment: @Jacinto o meu instinto é o mesmo que o teu. Nem sequer pensei na palavra como *guji*.

Comment: Eu também, "góji". Curiosamente, a palavra original lê-se "gou-ji". (Carreguem no símbolo de som **[nesta página](https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E6%9E%B8%E6%9D%9E)** do google translate - ali por baixo da caixa de texto grande do lado esquerdo.)